# Internal Server Error in saving data via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am trying to save to a database but fails with "500 (Internal Server Error)". Input boxes are dynamically generated. Below are my codes:

VIEW

```
<form class="add_new_inventory form-inline" role="form" id="add_new_inventory" method="post">
<tr>
    <td colspan="12">
    <button id="btn_save_inventory" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="save_inventory()">Submit All</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>

function save_inventory(){
            if(confirm("Are you done?")){
                var url="<?php echo site_url('commissary/add_multiple_inventories')?>";
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type:"POST",
                    data:$('#add_new_inventory').serialize(),
                    datatype:"JSON",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        // location.reload();
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function add_multiple_inventories(){
            $date_added=$this->input->post('date_added');
            $item_name=$this->input->post('item_name[]');
            $quantity=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('quantity[]'));
            $amount=$this->input->post('amount[]');

            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($item_name);$i++){
                $dataset[$i]=array(
                    'item_name'=>$item_name,
                    'date_added'=>$date_added,
                    'quantity'=>$quantity,
                    'amount'=>$amount,
                    'added_by'=>$this->session->userdata['username']
                );
            }
            $result=$this->commissary_model->insert_multiple_inventories($dataset);
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE));
        }
```

MODEL

```
public function insert_multiple_inventories($data){
        $this->db->insert_batch('piercapitan.com_inv',$data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

I get this error: `jquery.js:9536 POST http://localhost/pier_capitan/index.php/commissary/add_multiple_inventories 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It is not hitting controller at all. Please check browser console for more errors. can you share your ajax code.

Comment: where is the script function save_inventory()??

Comment: remove the [] from the array names

Comment: I use the [] for saving multiple dynamically created input boxes.

Comment: `$this->input->post('item_name');` should give you a array, `item_name[]` may alert you that the values doesn't exit

Comment: Thanks madalin ivascu. But what I did was different from what you suggested. Instead of removing the [],  I did this ------ '$dataset[$i]=array(
     'item_name'=>$item_name[$i],
     'date_added'=>$date_added,
     'quantity'=>$quantity[$i],
     'amount'=>$amount[$i],
     'added_by'=>$this->session->userdata['username']
    );    I added the $i in the item_name[$i]